# Testing PHP and HTML At The Same Time

Tags: php, html, testing, server-side

I am using a php include("   "); code to load a navigation bar on multiple blog pages from a PHP file named menu.php

I am really new to PHP and I can not figure out how to test it and see the results on the HTML page. Is there anything like a codepen or fiddle for HTML and PHP testing? Is there anything else I can use to test it? (I tried using XAMPP, couldn't figure it out)

HTML:

```
<aside id="blogroll">
<? php include("menu.php"); ?>
</aside>
```

PHP (menu.php):

```
<html>
<nav id="blog-catagories">
    <ul id="catagories">
        <li class="cat">Title</li>        
        <li class="cat">Title</li>
        <li class="cat">Title</li>
        <li class="cat">Title</li>
        <li class="cat">Title</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. 
The the best form is use Xampp.

Just install the Xampp in your operational system.
After this, just go to Windows Drive > Xampp > htdocs and **create a folder**.

Now, create a file (can be what you want) like index.php.

Well. Open your xampp panel. Just go to C:\xampp and start the xampp-control.exe (is better create a shortcut to your desktop).

When opened, start the apache and the mysql.

Well, just acess localhost/(the directory that you created) using your browser.

(If you are using Wordpress, go to **localhost/phpmyadmin**, create a database (can be anyone). Move all the files to the main directory of your folder, open the url in your browser, put the database that you created and use the root as database username, and let the password field empty, and progress with the installation).

Good studies.

Comment: I decided to give Xampp another go and by using your instructions I was able to achieve the results I was looking for. Thanks!